# jQuery UI sortable/draggable - with palette (copy/remove instead of moving)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I've got a simple setup using jQuery UI's default sortable/draggable functionality.

I now need to add a 'palette' which will will be a list of all items in all lists (and some that may not be in any lists). Like this:

```
<ul id="palette" class="ui-sortable">
 <li class="used">A</li>
 <li>B</li>
 <li class="used">C</li>
 <li class="used">D</li>
 <li>E</li>
 <li>F</li>
</ul>

<ol id="box1" class="ui-sortable box">
 <li>A</li>
 <li>D</li>
</ol>

<ol id="box2" class="ui-sortable box">
</ol>

<ol id="box3" class="ui-sortable box">
 <li>C</li>
</ol>
```

At the moment, the palette doesn't do anything different - dragging items in and out simply moves them.

The functionality I need is that when I drag out of the palette, it copies rather than moving, and when I drag into the palette, it removes from the source list but doesn't add to the palette. (The boxes can store multiple copies of palette items.)

I've used the sortable's `receive` event to create something that does all this - and I've added that as an answer below - but **I want some things that my existing solution doesn't provide**:

- preserve (visually, at least) the item in the palette from start of drag (rather than restoring it after dropping).
- persist the original palette order, preventing sortability (but preserving ability to connect with it from boxes).

**Can anyone suggest how best to implement these?**

Answer (score 1):

> preserve (visually, at least) the item in the palette 
>   from start of drag (rather than restoring it after dropping).

I presume you've already tried setting the palette's sortable helper to 'clone'?

```
var SortParams = {
  ...,
  helper: "clone",
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my current solution:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

 <title>jQuery UI Sortable / Palette test</title>

 <style>
  *{margin:0;padding:0;}

  ul,ol
  {list-style: none;}

  #palette
  {
   display: block;
   width: 114px;
   margin: 5px;

   float:left;clear:none;

   background: yellow;
  }

  .box
  {
   display:block;
   width: 114px;
   min-height: 5em;
   margin: 5px;

   float: left; clear:none;

   background:silver;
  }

  .box li,#palette li
  {
   display: block;
   width: 32px;
   height: 32px;
   margin: 2px;

   float: left; clear:none;

   text-align: center;
   border: solid 1px black;
  }

  #palette li{font-weight:bold}
  #palette li.used{font-weight:normal}

  #palette .ui-sortable-placeholder
  {
   display:none;
  }

 </style>

 <script src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
 <script src="jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js"></script>

 <script>
  $j = jQuery.noConflict();

  $j(document).ready(init);

  function init()
  {
   var SortParams =
   { connectWith:'.box,#palette'
   , dropOnEmpty:true
   , receive: doPaletteMagic
   }

   $j('.box,#palette').sortable( SortParams )
  }

  function doPaletteMagic( event , ui )
  {
   if ( ui.sender.is('#palette') )
   {
    ui.item
     .clone()
     .addClass('used')
     .appendTo('#palette')

    // TODO: fix #palette ordering
   }
   else
   if ( ui.item.parent().is('#palette') )
   {
    var ItemContent = ui.item.text();

    ui.item.remove()

    if ( ! isUsed( ItemContent ) )
    {
     $j('#palette li:contains('+ItemContent+')')
      .removeClass('used')
      ;
    }

   }
  }

  function isUsed(Content)
  {
   return ($j('.box li:contains('+Content+')').length > 0)
  }

 </script>

<body>

 <ul id="palette" class="ui-sortable">
  <li class="used">A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li class="used">C</li>
  <li class="used">D</li>
  <li>E</li>
  <li>F</li>
 </ul>

 <ol id="box1" class="ui-sortable box">
  <li>A</li>
  <li>D</li>
 </ol>

 <ol id="box2" class="ui-sortable box">
 </ol>

 <ol id="box3" class="ui-sortable box">
  <li>C</li>
 </ol>

 <br class="break"/>

</html>
```